# Unity InputField on HoloLens, keyboard disappears

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard, hololens, input-field

I'm trying to add an input field on my HoloLens (1st gen) app and when I click on the field the keyboard appears but then disappears.

**The problem**
My input field is an **Unity UI input field** and when I click using a finger tap on the input field I can hear a click sound and the keyboard appears but disappears right after.
[image]

**What I've tried**
According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/keyboard-input-in-unity), using Unity UI input field or TextMeshPro input field should allow me to use the keyboard in order to fill the input.

Any solution on how to fix this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `TextMeshPro Input Field` solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have also had same problem. Not only on the Hololens 1 but also on the Hololens 2.

I was using Unity 2021 versions but then rolled back to Unity 2019 version. It seemed to solve the problem of keyboard disappearing suddenly. You can also get more related information about the unity versions and MRTK keyboard here [Keyboard disappearing all of a sudden](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10191).According to the link , certain 2020 or 2019 Unity version seems to have this issue fixed,but for me, Unity 2020 versions did not solve the issue.

On other hand,there is also one other issue with keyboard; when typed on the keyboard the cursor position did not seem to properly move with text and sometimes the text would get jumbled up. However, it was only around 20% of the time, so i went ahead with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm on Unity 2019.4.36f1 and I have the issue. I guess it will be harder than that sadly